# How to insert a character in a tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm creating a Can Message prototype, the format for this it's something like this
xx.xx.xx.xx

The x's are characters from user input, and the points need to be inserted automatically. The user type the first 2 characters then a point it is inserted in the entry box, visually. Then the user type 2 more characters ...

I accomplished something with the insert method, but if I want to delete the point.. maybe I want to change the first 2 characters or whatever, I can't, it won't let me delete it, only if I use ctr+a.

This can message entry box it's from a larger program, but to make things easier, I tested just this one thing in a test file, below you can see.
`your`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk("")

def callback(*args):
    if len(entrybox_var.get()) == 2:
        entrybox.insert(2, ".")

entrybox_var = StringVar()
entrybox_var.trace("w", callback)


entrybox = Entry(root, textvariable= entrybox_var)
entrybox.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

`text`

Comment: Your title asks how to insert text, the body of the question says you're trying to delete but can't, but the code doesn't show you attempting to delete. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You are right, the title asks how to insert the text because the way I insert what I need it s not the correct way.
The code doesn't show my attempting because I'm using the key "del", from my keyboard :), at the end, the user it's going to use the key "del" from his keyboard to delete something.

Comment: Try looking at [Validating a text entry](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781788622301/1/ch01lvl1sec07/validating-a-text-entry).